# Convert string to timestamp in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a variable recover from ajax and in  the controller

```
dd($gethour);
"Sat Oct 26 2019 00:00:04 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)"
$from = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y H:i:s', $gethour);
dd($form);
```

Result:false

My problem is how to convert string to timestamp seen in the base HoursPass is a type timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you could start with a real timestamp which is long number. But otherwise you could do it this way:

```
$gethour = "Sat Oct 26 2019 00:00:04 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)";

$chunks = explode(' ', $gethour);

$from = new \DateTime($chunks[1] . ' ' . $chunks[2] . ' ' . $chunks[3] . ' ' . $chunks[4]);
$from->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($chunks[5]));

echo $from->format('d-m-Y H:i:s P'); // 26-10-2019 09:00:04 +02:00
```

Comment: thank you it works but just for recovery after in the twig

how to recover just hours and minutes

Comment: Not sure about your question. but in twig you can use the date filter to get a string out of the DateTime object: {{ post.published_at|date("H:i") }}

Answer (score -1):

you can exam this way :

```
date("m-d-y H:i:s", strtotime($gethour));
```

this way is answered for me.